# Invoking subversion (svn <stuff>) using shell_exec

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a lot of svn blames on a project and I've done a PHP script for it.

The problem is, while echo shell_exec( 'ls' ) shows the files of the (svn-versioned) directory  the executed file is on, `shell_exec( 'svn info' )` or the like, returns NULL. Any idea why? Of course, it works from the terminal.

I'm on OSX Leopard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a few things: Volume of Data, Permissions on svn command...

Also try:

```
exec('svn info',$execOut);
print_r($execOut);
```

Answer (score 1):

Working fine on OSX Lion:

```php
<?php
echo shell_exec('svn info');
?>
```

When I run `php test.php` on it.

You could try adding `2>&1` to the end of the string to see if something is being missed on stderr?